# Absolutely positioned element not correctly aligned inside relative div

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, css-position

In my Cordova based app I've got a div that's supposed to show a graphical representation of a UK Licence Plate.

This is how it's supposed to look:

[image: intended appearance]

(how it displays on iOS - Cordova ver 3.8)

However, on Android, Cordova ver 4.1.1, it appears like this instead:

[image: actual appearance]

The snippet is as follows, demonstrating the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
.registration-plate-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.registration-plate-ui {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8d038 0%, #f5ca2e 100%);
    padding: .25em 1em .25em 1.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ddd;
    position: relative;
    font-family: helvetica, ariel, sans-serif;
}

.registration-plate-ui:before {
    content: 'GB';
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #063298;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    color: #f8d038;
    font-size: .5em;
    line-height: 85px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.registration-plate-ui:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px dashed #f8d038;
}
```

```html
<div class='registration-plate-container'><span class='registration-plate-ui'>AB12 CDE</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.registration-plate-container {
    /* text-align: center; */ /* throws off position property centering */
    position: relative;       /* this is the actual container element,
                                 so set the boundaries here for abspos children */
     height: 75px;            /* for demo only */
     border: 1px dashed red;  /* for demo only */
}

.registration-plate-ui {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8d038 0%, #f5ca2e 100%);
    padding: .25em 1em .25em 1.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ddd;
    position: absolute;          /* changed from 'relative` */
    left: 50%;                   /* center horizontally */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* center fine-tuning */
    font-family: helvetica, ariel, sans-serif;
}

.registration-plate-ui:before {
    content: 'GB';
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #063298;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;               /* tell it where to go */
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    color: #f8d038;
    font-size: .5em;
    line-height: 85px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.registration-plate-ui:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px dashed #f8d038;
}
```

```html
<div class='registration-plate-container'><span class='registration-plate-ui'>AB12 CDE</span></div>
```

Comment: This fixes the positioning of the before element, however it overlaps the content that is below it - how do I fix this?

Comment: @Ryan Change the z-position of div.. if i'm understanding what you're asking

Comment: If you mean below it on the y-axis, you need to set a height for the container. I updated my answer.

Comment: If so then @Michael_B is correct. Or you can set a margin either way will work.

Comment: Your absolutely positioned child elements are *out of the normal flow*, meaning they don't take up space. Hence, their container collapses. That's why I added height and border in my example. Remove the height to see what happens. Add height to push down elements below it.

Comment: Changing the position back to relative on .registration-plate-ui also resolves the issue, as long as the container div is also relatively positioned.